# jQuery GalleryView Wordpress Plugin is giving me "is not a function" error

Tags: jquery, wordpress, galleryview

I'm attempting to use NextGen Gallery plugin with the new jquery slideshow plugin GalleryView. These are supposed to work lovely together.

NGG works on my site if I just go with the default Flash player but that's not going to work for me. So I installed the new GalleryView plugin and put the short code as needed but as you can see on this page

http://www.blissyfit.com/2010/07/find-your-wedding-dress-at-the-mall/

thumbnails appear but the slideshow doesn't and a javascript error is being thrown "galleryView is not a function"

Though I see galleryview defined in an included js file.

I've tried contacting the plugin creator and posting at the wordpress forum but no replies either place. I'm hoping someone here can offer some insight.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your last include here:

```
http://www.blissyfit.com/wp-content/themes/yamidoo_12/js/slider.js
```

*Also* contains jQuery 1.3.2 inside the file, so it's overwriting the `jQuery` object and all your plugins.

To get a version without the jQuery library embedded: On the [jQuery Tools download page](http://flowplayer.org/tools/download/index.html) be sure to uncheck the jQuery selection at the top, since you already have it in the page.

---

Note that besides this include, you already including jQuery twice before the above problem, so it's actually being loaded 3 times.  **1.3.2** is being loaded here:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js?ver=3.0.1'></script>
```

Then **1.4.2** is being loaded here::

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.blissyfit.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.4.2'></script>
```

Since this destroys the jQuery UI includes as well, I'd remove these two script elements:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js?ver=3.0.1'></script> 
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js?ver=3.0.1'></script>
```

Currently, they're just slowing down the page and being overwritten anyway.

Comment: Thanks. I'd noticed the extra jquery calls above the issue but didn't realize slider was resetting the whole thing. Fixed via that tools download page link. Will clean up the other mess next. Thanks for the extra help!